# Measurement of Spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

Suppose we have a spin state for a spin 1 particle in $S_z$ basis defined by a column matrix $|Ψ\rangle=(a,b,c)$.What is the probability of getting $\hbar$ if we measure $S_z$ for a state $S_x|Ψ\rangle$ ?

I don't know how to solve this kind of problems and so it would be of great help if someone tells me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can start by finding out what is the matrix representation of $S_x$

Answer (score 1):

The representation of $S_z$ in its own basis is trivial to write down:
$$S_z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
in units $\hbar=1$.
Now, using the standard arguments of angular momentum algebra, we have:
$$S_+=S_x +iS_y$$
$$S_-=S_x -iS_y$$
Further,we know that
$$S_+ \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$S_+ \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$S_+ \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}=0$$
Knowing the action of an operator on all basis elements, uniquely determines the operator. Simply reading off the operator from the above relations:
$$S_+=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Similarly we have,
$$S_-=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Hence, we finally have the expression:
$$S_x=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Now, its plain as day to see that the probability of measuring spin up is simply:
$\frac{|b|^2}{4}$

Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you get the expression for $S_z$? It is not trivial for me to see why it should be the expression that you gave.

Comment: well, $S_z$ better be diagonal in its own basis(this is the meaning of choosing the basis formed out of the eigenvectors of $S_z$). It is known that the eigenvalues are -1,0,1. These must occupy the diagonal positions in $S_z$. And thats what has been written down.

Comment: Is there any reason for the particular ordering of the eigenvalues? The resulting matrices should obey particular commutation relations. Can you show that they do, or is there a quick way to see it?

Comment: To answer your first question. No there is no strict ordering to the eigenvalues. However, It is convention to assign the canonical basis vector $e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}^T$, the highest eigenvalue. To answer your second question, recall that action of $S_+$ and $S_-$ on the basis vectors are found using the commutation relationships. So, checking if the final answers satisfy them is a mere consistency check. A good way to see it immediately is to calculate $S_+ S_z |j,m\rangle$using the commutation relationships.